# How to zip/ archive my bitmap array in android ?

Tags: android, bitmap, zip

I would like to know that, I have an image and broken into pieces 9 * 9 stored those in bitmap array. now my question, is it possible to make zip file of those bitmap array? like, cutted_images_bitmap_array.ZIP file.

Below you can observe my code.

```
private void break_up_image(Bitmap Bsbmp, String Bnum) {
        int rows, cols, hgt, wdt;
        int number_bixs=Integer.valueOf(Bnum);

        cutted_images_bitmap_array = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(number_bixs);

        Bitmap Bb = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bsbmp, width_img_view,height_img_view, true);
        rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(number_bixs);
        hgt = Bb.getHeight() / rows;
        wdt = Bb.getWidth() / cols;
        int yaxis = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            int xaxis = 0;
            for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++) {
                cut.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(Bb, xaxis, yaxis, wdt, hgt));
                xaxis += wdt;
            }
            yaxis += hgt;
        }
}
```

How to make a zip of those bitmap array?  any alternative solution or suggestion i will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save them first and then Zip those individual images to zip files.

```
try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```